# split one column from import into 2 column in database

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis

i have a file i need to import that has a column with the settings A, S and B in them,

i would like to split this column and and all the A's go into a column but be reset to a 1 and the rest to go into another column and changed to a 1.

is this possible in derived columns?

Comment: what you mean by "derived columns" in that context? What are your derived columns? Without the last sentence, the answer would be a simple INSERT INTO ... SELECT over a plain import table i, comparing the colum value with 'A', 'B' and 'C' for each target column respectively?

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to mention this is in an SSIS module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to create two derived columns using an If statement

`([Product Type Code] == "A" ? "1" : "0")`

and invert the outcome for the other derived column.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking for but how about something like this:

```
SELECT
  CASE ImportColumn WHEN 'A' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END AS [A Column]
, CASE ImportColumn WHEN 'A' THEN NULL ELSE 1 END AS [Other Column]
FROM
  Import
```

When the value is 'A' then a row will be added with the first col 1 and 2nd col null.
When the value is not 'A' then a row will be added with null in first col and 1 in the second.  Is that what you meant?

Comment: Your second case seems wrong. Should compare with S. One more such CASE for B missing.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to mention this is in an SSIS module.

Comment: @user492238 - First column is 1 when 'A', the second column is 1 when everything but 'A'.